# CSS Animation Glitch, on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an over hover animation glitch. When you're near the bottom of the item, it jumps, uncontrollably, is there any fix?

Sample image :

[image]

```
.btn:hover{
    background-color: #2795de;  
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -1.3em);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -1.3em);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -1.3em);
}
```

Comment: Would be great if you could include a little extra code, such as your html for the button?

Comment: I guess there is some invisible padding or margin... Please paste your code with Css

Comment: If you move the button upwards on hover, it's no wonder it starts jumping if you point the cursor to the bottom of it, is the moment the button moves, it no longer in hover state...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) on .btn

```
.btn{
 -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  }

 .btn:hover{
  background-color:#2795de; 
 -moz-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -o-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -webkit-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
  }
```

DEMO

```css
.btn{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background: red;
 -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 2s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  }

 .btn:hover{
  background-color:#2795de; 
 -moz-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -o-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -webkit-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
  }
```

```html
<div class=btn > HOVER ME </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it stop the hover effect, or going up, flat out?

Comment: There it is!! You've fixed it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The jump is being caused by the `translate` property in your CSS definitions.

If the jump is unintended, you can simply remove it from your CSS definition :

```
    .btn:hover{
          background-color:#2795de; 
    /*   -moz-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
         -o-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
         -webkit-transform:translate(0,-1.3em); */
    }
```

Or you can split the css into two parts :

```
    .btn{
         -moz-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
         -o-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
         -webkit-transform:translate(0,-1.3em); 
    }

    .btn:hover {
          background-color:#2795de; 
    }
```

Comment: The jump is intended, but that uncontrollable up and down is irritating, and unprofessional.

I need it to simple go up, on hover, and go down, off hover, basically to stabilize it. When you're on the bottom part of it, it just flutters.

Comment: You can follow the update of @Tambo, Adding a transitional ease to the translation process will stop the jumping

Answer (score 0):

remove your btn.hover and write only btn  because hover is take event when your mouse cuser comes up on your button(.btn). so remove it.

and write

```
`.btn{
  background-color:#2795de; 
 -moz-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -o-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
 -webkit-transform:translate(0,-1.3em);
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your button is only going up on :hover but the distance that it goes up puts your button out of :hover state and it goes down. When it goes down it goes under the cursor again and goes into :hover state.

depending on what you want to achieve but instead of actually moving your button up on hover just change the background-color of it. You'll find people will be unable to actually click on it. Or just add a large padding-bottom so when button goes up  the cursor still stays in :hover state.